# Model with "linked-list" type self-reference, how to get only those which are not referenced?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Rails 5, ActiveRecord on PostgreSQL database. Have class with a `previous_id` column, like so:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :previous, class_name: 'Event'
end
```

I would like to get all Events that have no other Events referencing them as a "previous" Event. How can I make a query to do this?

I can obviously do something like:

```
Event.where.not(id: Event.pluck(:previous_id))
```

But my sense is that there is a more performant way to achieve this.

Comment: in SQL you'd do a left-self-anti-join. Which probably sounds like nonsense. The idea is to do `event AS referenced left join event AS referencing ON (referencing.id = referenced.belongs_to) WHERE referencing.id IS NULL`. So it returns only rows from `referenced` where no `referencing` row exists.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @Craig Ringer's comment with some ruby code that will produce his recommended SQL, you can do something like this

```
Event.joins("left join events referencing on referencing.previous_id = events.id")
     .where("referencing.id is null")
```